# how to getvalue of textarea in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I am using `react-final-form` and `TextareaAutosize`in my example .I am trying to get the value of `text-area` but not able to do that.
I am able to get value of `input` field but not `textarea`

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-rd3rc

```
 <div>
            <label>Text area Name</label>
            <Field
              component={TextareaAutosize}
              type="textarea"
              name="operatingPinCode"
              placeholder="Notes"
              label="About"
            />
          </div>
```

API link
https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/simple

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-textarea-autosize

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your final-form code is working fine. The problem I think lies with TextAreaAutosize, since it doesn't know how to pass data directly to your form. So you might need to add a handler on that field for the onChange event.

Based on the final form documentation, this code sample below seems to work just fine:[sandbox-code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-y6c2l) Just checkout the second attempt section.

Comment: thanks for help..!! it working fine...!! is possible to remove or fine "draggable icon" from `textarea`

Comment: This not work, and the alert not show the text with the linke breaks, show just a line with the text\text\text\

Comment: @ddaudiosolutions I do not see exactly what does not work. this answer is also 3 and half years old. the author confirmed at that time that it worked for his issue.

Comment: yes works to create the text during the form, but if then you did not explain that you need to add 
white-space: pre-line; or white-space: pre-wrap; the user can not see the result in the final view.
I think that would be useful if you add this in the response.
When i can i give again a positive point.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get value by this pop:**

```
    `onChange={(event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    }}`
```